# Fetch values from the selected rows and calculate its average

Tags: mysql, select, database-table

I am working with SQL

I have a table named as `review` like this with following rows and columns

```
rating | status
-------|----------
5      | 1
5      | 1
4      | 1
2      | 0
5      |-1
```

I want to calculate the average of rating values when status is 1 and ignore the rows  rating with status other than 1

How can I do this?

This is my try :

```
select * from review where status in (
select status from review
group by status having count(*) > 1
)
```

I was able to select the rows with status 1 but how can I fetch the values in rating column from selected rows and calculate its average?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this `query` will `return` `Average` rating

```
Select avg(rating) from review WHERE status=1
```